# High CPU usage by only 4 users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

New as DBA and I feel really confused with this...

4 users working, doing stuff with macros, commited_snapshot ON, 90% cpu ran `sp_blitz` and found that 1 query is using more than 50 plan caches...

Ran `sp_blitzcache` to find that this query is using % CPU (type): 70

```
SELECT     
999999 AS RECNO,    
CAST(db_name() AS VARCHAR(128)) AS CATALOG_NAME,    CAST(user_name(o.uid) AS VARCHAR(128)) AS SCHEMA_NAME,    
CAST(o.name AS VARCHAR(128)) AS TABLE_NAME,    
CAST(x.name AS VARCHAR(128)) AS INDEX_NAME,    
CAST(c.name AS VARCHAR(128)) AS COLUMN_NAME,    
xk.keyno AS COLUMN_POSITION,    
CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(1)) AS PKEY_NAME,    
(CASE WHEN x.status & 0x800 <> 0 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) +     (CASE WHEN x.status & 0x2 <> 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)     AS INDEX_TYPE,    
(CASE WHEN indexkey_property(x.id, x.indid, 1, N'isdescending') <> 0 THEN 'D' ELSE 'A' END) AS SORT_ORDER,    
CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(1)) AS FILTER   
FROM     
sysobjects o, sysindexes x, syscolumns c, sysindexkeys xk   
WHERE     o.id = x.id     
AND o.id = c.id     
AND o.id = xk.id     
AND x.indid = xk.indid     
AND c.colid = xk.colid     
AND xk.keyno <= x.keycnt     
AND o.xtype <> 'S'     
AND LEFT(x.name, 8/*_WA_Sys_*/) <> '_WA_Sys_'    
AND o.name LIKE 'Triangle'    
ORDER BY x.name, xk.keyno
```

'Triangle' is one of the database tables, but I don't really know what the query does or if this is a query generated by the application the users are using.

This other query gets % CPU (Type): 22

```
SELECT     
999999 AS RECNO,    
CAST(db_name() AS VARCHAR(128)) AS CATALOG_NAME,    CAST(user_name(o.uid) AS VARCHAR(128)) AS SCHEMA_NAME,    
CAST(o.name AS VARCHAR(128)) AS TABLE_NAME,    
CAST(x.name AS VARCHAR(128)) AS INDEX_NAME,    
CAST(c.name AS VARCHAR(128)) AS COLUMN_NAME,    
xk.keyno AS COLUMN_POSITION,    CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(1)) AS PKEY_NAME,    (CASE WHEN x.status & 0x800 <> 0 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) +     (CASE WHEN x.status & 0x2 <> 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)     AS INDEX_TYPE,    (CASE WHEN indexkey_property(x.id, x.indid, 1, N'isdescending') <> 0 THEN 'D' ELSE 'A' END) AS SORT_ORDER,    CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(1)) AS FILTER   FROM     
sysobjects o, sysindexes x, syscolumns c, sysindexkeys xk   
WHERE     o.id = x.id     
AND o.id = c.id     
AND o.id = xk.id     
AND x.indid = xk.indid     
AND c.colid = xk.colid     
AND xk.keyno <= x.keycnt     
AND o.xtype <> 'S'     
AND LEFT(x.name, 8/*_WA_Sys_*/) <> '_WA_Sys_'    
AND o.name LIKE 'Vector'    
ORDER BY x.name, xk.keyno
```

Vector is another Database table...

When I execute both of them returns 0 rows,

What can I do? I don't know what to do at this point...

Comment: Looks like these queries (both) are just returning the table schemas of the `Triangle` and `Vector` tables. I'm not sure this is the cause of your performance issues. Are we to understand that these queries represent 90% of the cpu load of the *SQL Server instance*, or 90% of the *machine* as a whole? Could you clarify a bit on your specific problem?

Comment: That 2 queries are consuming the 90% of the server CPU and are being executed 6.000times every minute, I can post a Screenshot from Brent Ozar script results if helps to clarify.

Comment: that's complete madness. Use `sp_who2` to find who's running that query, the disable the account and/or speak to the developer.

Comment: It is part of an application I just started to administrate a server and found this complete chaos :/

Comment: If the users arent complaining about performance, resource governor can throttle those problematic user's queries.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that queries are running under the session that the user creates when using his application/macros so there is little I can do to use Resource Governor to limit this query (I think).

Thanks for all the comments, lets see if we can find a solution haha.

Comment: Either dedicate this particular instance (and machine) to this app and ignore it until there's a complaint (and then go on to option 2), or get the app developers/vendor to fix it (which is option 2).  If it's a shared instance/machine, then get the suffering users to pile onto the app developers/vendor or help get budget for more equipment.

Comment: I will try to FORCE parametrization and see if helps reducing the CPU workload...

At this time I think the problem is the crappy processor and the bad programming on the VBA code of the excel macros, I'm trying to force them to use Parametrized Stored Procedures.